# Problem with @NotNull annotation it's definitely ignoring

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have dto class with validation field and when I sending the request I expect Exception with validation error but I got code 201. I added dependency javax.validation and a @Valid annotation before @RequestBody. I exhausted ideas how to solve it
Bellow I added my dto class and Contoller class

dto:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class AddressDto {
  
  @NotBlank(message = "The country is required.")
  private String country;

  @NotBlank(message = "The city is required.")
  private String city;

  @NotBlank(message = "The Zip code is required.")
  private String zipCode;

  @NotBlank(message = "The street name is required.")
  private String street;

  private String state;
}
```

controller:

```
package com.controller;

import com.model.dto.AddressDto;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AddressController {

  @PostMapping("/test")
  public ResponseEntity<AddressDto> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody AddressDto registerUserDto) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(registerUserDto, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

request and response from postman
[image: REQUEST&RESPONSEPOSTMAN]

Comment: Have you tried `@NotNull` from javax.validation.constraints.NotNull?

Comment: yes, with the same result like upper :(

Comment: Have you override `MethodArgumentNotValidException` somewhere and not handling it properly?

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using? have you added a spring-boot-starter-validation dependency?

Comment: @Enfieldli I didn't ovverride MethodArgumentNotValidException, I have class with ControllerAdvice annotation but i just handle EntityNotFoundException

Comment: @criztovyl I'm using spring boot  <version>2.4.2</version> I didn.t add spring-boot-starter-validation dependency because I have spring-boot-web dependency and web include validation am I right?

Comment: You need `<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId></dependency>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since Spring Boot 2.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters) you explicitly need to add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-validation`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```